# access callback (onPictureTaken) variable in Main Activity

Tags: java, android, android-layout, callback, android-camera

I looked all over stackoverflow to find a solution, i found a few but i can't seem to get them working. I currently obtain the response from my api, which is an image that i save in a bitmap here:

What i want to do is show this on the mainactivity below the barcode result.

```
BarcodeCaptureActivity.java

                    mCameraSource.takePicture(null, new CameraSource.PictureCallback(){
            @Override
            public  void onPictureTaken (byte[] data){
                Context context = getApplicationContext();
                CharSequence text = "Hello toast!";
                int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;

                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
                toast.show();

                String imgData = Base64.encodeToString(data, Base64.NO_WRAP);



                JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject();
                try{
                    jsonObj.put("barcode", finalBest.displayValue);
                    jsonObj.put("imgurl", imgData);
                    Context jsonSuc = getApplicationContext();
                    CharSequence jsonText = "Json successful";
                    int jsonDur = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;

                    Toast jsonToast = Toast.makeText(jsonSuc, jsonText, jsonDur);
                    jsonToast.show();
                }
                catch (JSONException e){
                    Context context2 = getApplicationContext();
                    CharSequence text2 = "Bye toast!";
                    int duration2 = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;

                    Toast toast2 = Toast.makeText(context2, text2, duration2);
                    toast2.show();
                }
                try {
                    Context connTe = getApplicationContext();
                    CharSequence connectText = "Connection function successful";
                    int connectDur = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;

                    Toast connectToast = Toast.makeText(connTe, connectText, connectDur);
                    connectToast.show();

                    URL url = new URL("http://MYAPI");
                    HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                    conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
                    conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=UTF-8");
                    conn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
                    conn.setDoOutput(true);
                    conn.setDoInput(true);

                    Log.i("JSON", jsonObj.toString());
                    DataOutputStream os = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());
                    //os.writeBytes(URLEncoder.encode(jsonParam.toString(), "UTF-8"));
                    os.writeBytes(jsonObj.toString());

                    os.flush();
                    os.close();

                    //new
                    String json_response = "";
                    InputStreamReader in = new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream());
                    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(in);
                    String resptext = "";
                    while ((resptext = br.readLine()) != null) {
                        json_response += resptext;
                    }
                    json_response = json_response.substring(15);
                    json_response = json_response.substring(0, json_response.length()-2);

                    try {
                        URL url2 = new URL(json_response);
                        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url2.openConnection();
                        connection.setDoInput(true);
                        connection.connect();
                        InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();
                        myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input); //HEre myBitmap contains an image





                    }catch (Exception e){
                        Log.d(TAG,e.getMessage());
                    }

                    Log.i("STATUS", String.valueOf(conn.getResponseCode()));
                    Log.i("MSG", conn.getResponseMessage());

                    conn.disconnect();
                }
                catch (Exception a) {
                    a.printStackTrace();
                }

                // Do something with the data (this is the JPEG image)

            }
        }
        );
        Intent data = new Intent();
        data.putExtra(BarcodeObject, best);
        data.putExtra("mybitmap", myBitmap); // Here myBitmap is empty
        setResult(CommonStatusCodes.SUCCESS, data);
        finish();
        return true;
    }
    return false;
```

What can i do to access this variable in the Main Activity so i can draw the bitmap on the layout?

Comment: what is the server response?

Comment: For now it gives an URL to an image, so the url is taken out and from that URL i download an image that is saved in the Bitmap. When i view the Bitmap in the debugger it shows me the correct image.

Comment: and your bitmap object is different of null before sending ?

Comment: Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input); At this point it contains the image.

Comment: yes, is 'myBitmap' != null ?

Comment: Yeah it is != null. But when i Intent data = new Intent();
        data.putExtra(BarcodeObject, best); 
       data.putExtra("mybitmap", myBitmap)
        setResult(CommonStatusCodes.SUCCESS, data);
        finish();
        return true; it is null.

Comment: could you put the code when you parse your bitmap from the other activity?

Comment: It already fails at creating the intent. Intent data = new Intent(); data.putExtra(BarcodeObject, best); data.putExtra("mybitmap", myBitmap) setResult(CommonStatusCodes.SUCCESS, data); finish();. Then myBitmap = null

Comment: its more better to pass the url to main actiivty and download image there if the only usage of image is in main activity

Comment: what do you mean by 'fails at creating the intent' ?

Comment: But i can't access any variable in the code i put above.

Comment: Well when i create the intent and pass myBitmap, at that point it's null.

Comment: I updated my code, added 2 comments to show where bitmap != null and where bitmap = null

Comment: put your completed method, looks like you are using asynchronous method

Comment: Yeah it is asynchronous.

Comment: could you put the source code? (complete)

Comment: I added it to the question

Comment: Yes, it's asynchronous and you are sending the result in synchronous way. 
Why don't you send  Intent .... setResult(CommonStatusCodes.SUCCESS, data); below Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);

Comment: I'll try right now

Comment: That way the MainActivity doesn't get the Barcodeobject and the statuscode